# How to grep for two words with a tab in between them

Tags: bash, grep

I've got a file with with a list of words each delimited by tabs. I'm trying to use grep to search for two of the words, but I can't figure out how to include the tab in the search string. I've tried:

```
grep -i -e "word1 \tword2"
```

along with several variations, but I still can't figure it out. Anyhelp?

Comment: The answers below are helpful, but are also copying your example of a space followed by a tab. If your delimiter is _only_ a tab, adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

POSIXly:

```
grep "word1 $(printf '\t')word2" <file
```

Note that you need to escaped any characters in `word1` and `word2` if they're expanded by the shell.

In `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh` variants, you can use:

```
grep 'word1'$'\t''word2' <file
```

---

If you don't mind switching to `awk`:

```
awk '/word1 \tword2/' <file
```

will work in all POSIX systems.

Comment: `$()` is bash syntax.

Comment: @User112638726: It's POSIX, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03

Answer (score -2):

You might like to try this:

```
grep -e "word1.*word2" inputfile.txt
```

Comment: That does not match a tab character between two words.

Comment: I think you have `.` and `*` around the wrong way.

Comment: Answered before I had my coffee. Thanks @DarkHeart